# LINQ merging two Lists and grouping by timestamps

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Good morning, I've got two lists that I need to merge together and create a data table from, I've got the following block of code:

```
private static DataTable GetDataTable(IList<DataValue> listOneDataValues,
                                            IList<DataValue> listTwoDataValues)
      {
         var dataTable = new DataTable();
         dataTable.Columns.Add("ColumnFromListOne");
         dataTable.Columns.Add("ColumnFromListTwo");
         dataTable.Columns.Add("TimeStamp");

         //Group the lists together
         var query = (from listOne in listOneDataValues
                      from listTwo in listTwoDataValues
                      let columnFromListOne= listOne.DoubleValue
                      let columnFromListTwo= listTwo.DoubleValue
                      let timestamp = listOne.TimeStamp
                      where listOne.TimeStamp == listTwo.TimeStamp
                      select new {ColumnFromListTwo = columnFromListOne, ColumnFromListOne = columnFromListTwo, Timestamp = timestamp});


         foreach(var q in query)
            dataTable.Rows.Add(q.ColumnFromListOne, q.ColumnFromListTwo, q.TimeStamp);

         return dataTable;
      }
```

The problem is the two lists contain timestamps that are off by a matter of seconds, and they don't align at all, so my end result ends up with one or zero records in the datatable, even though each list contains 200+ records. I'm pretty bad with LINQ and would appreciate a point in the right direction. I guess I need to interpolate the timestamps before grouping, but I would like to know the best practice pattern for doing something like this.

Comment: How do you want to handle timestamps that are off by a few seconds?  They *are* different, so they should be treated as different.  You can round or truncate to the nearest minute, but what if the timestamps straddle that line?  You can find the distance between them, but if you have a lot of events you'll get overlap.

Comment: The lowest level of granularity is every 5 minutes. I'd need to round up or down to the nearest 5 minutes I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decide what an appropriate threshold is for calling two time stamps "equal" - knowing that too large a threshold will give you false positives and too small a threshold will prevent some records from joining.

From there just change your query to

```
     int threshold = 5;
     //Group the lists together
     var query = (from listOne in listOneDataValues
                  from listTwo in listTwoDataValues
                  where Math.Abs(
                                    (listOne.TimeStamp - listTwo.TimeStamp)
                                     .TotalSeconds
                                ) <= threshold
                  select new {
                                 ColumnFromListTwo = listTwo.DoubleValue,
                                 ColumnFromListOne = listOne.DoubleValue, 
                                 Timestamp = listOne.TimeStamp
                             });
```

Comment: Both are good answers, it's going to you for completeness though.

Answer (score 4):

You could change your `where` statement to

`where Math.Abs((listOne.TimeStamp - listTwo.TimeStamp).TotalSeconds) < 5`

This would consider two times differing by 5 seconds as 'the same'

Comment: I would avoid the magic number here.  Create an epsilon or threshold variable, and make sure to do some testing based on the data to determine what an appropriate value is.  The different may also be in milliseconds, not seconds.