# C# merge multiple lists based on timestamp

Tags: c#, json, linq, object

I have a data set that comes as a list of objects in C#, looking something below.

```
public class MotorDataModel
    {
        public DateTime timestamp { set; get; }
        public decimal MotorSpeed { set; get; }
        public decimal MotorTemp { set; get; }
        public decimal MotorKw{ set; get; }
    }


public class MotorModel
    {
        public string MotorName { set; get; }
        public List<MotorDataModel> MotorData { set; get; }
    }
```

When I do the query, I will have 1 or more MotorModel records coming back (say motor 1, 2, 3, ...), each with their own timestamps, and various data points at those time stamps.

I am then sending this data to a javascript charting library, which takes the data in as a data table (e.g. spreadsheet like format), such as:

TimeStamp |  Motor1:kW |  Motor1:Speed |  Motor1:Temp |  Motor2:kW   |Motor2:Speed ...

with the data following in rows.  The data will be grouped on the timestamp, which should be the within a couple minutes of each other, in a consistent increment (say 15 minutes).

The plan is to transform the data in C#, convert it to JSON, and and send it to the chart library (Google Chart).

I don't have to format this in C#, and could convert the Object list data in C# to JSON, and reformat it in javascript on the client, but it seems better to transform it at the server.

Either way, I am struggling on how to transform the data from a multiple list of objects to a "datatable" like view.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14816053/linq-merging-two-lists-and-grouping-by-timestamps) via LINQ seems to be close, but I have multiple lists of equipment, not a defined number.

I have also looked at just looping through and building the data table (or array), but unsure of what structure makes the most sense.

So, if anyone has done something similar, or has any feedback, it would be much appreciated.

**Suggested format for providing sample data**

Below is some sample data provided by BlueMonkMN. Please update the question providing sample data representative of your actual question.

```
     List<MotorModel> allData = new List<MotorModel>() {
        new MotorModel() {MotorName="Motor1", MotorData = new List<MotorDataModel> {
           new MotorDataModel(){timestamp=new DateTime(2016, 9, 18, 2, 56, 0), MotorSpeed=20.0M, MotorTemp=66.2M, MotorKw=5.5M},
           new MotorDataModel(){timestamp=new DateTime(2016, 9, 18, 3, 10, 30), MotorSpeed=10.0M, MotorTemp=67.0M, MotorKw=5.5M},
           new MotorDataModel(){timestamp=new DateTime(2016, 9, 18, 3, 25, 45), MotorSpeed=17.5M, MotorTemp=66.1M, MotorKw=5.8M},
           new MotorDataModel(){timestamp=new DateTime(2016, 9, 18, 3, 40, 23), MotorSpeed=22.2M, MotorTemp=65.8M, MotorKw=5.4M}
        }},
        new MotorModel() {MotorName="Motor2", MotorData = new List<MotorDataModel> {
           new MotorDataModel(){timestamp=new DateTime(2016, 9, 18, 2, 58, 0), MotorSpeed=21.0M, MotorTemp=67.2M, MotorKw=5.6M},
           new MotorDataModel(){timestamp=new DateTime(2016, 9, 18, 3, 11, 30), MotorSpeed=11.0M, MotorTemp=68.0M, MotorKw=5.6M},
           new MotorDataModel(){timestamp=new DateTime(2016, 9, 18, 3, 24, 45), MotorSpeed=18.5M, MotorTemp=67.1M, MotorKw=5.9M},
           new MotorDataModel(){timestamp=new DateTime(2016, 9, 18, 3, 39, 23), MotorSpeed=23.2M, MotorTemp=66.8M, MotorKw=5.5M}
        }}
     };
```

Comment: Your question would be clearer and easier to answer and test if you could provide a very small set of sample data that demonstrates the structure of the actual data you are trying to merge. For example, do you have multiple List<MotorDataModel> instances that you are trying to combine?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to share an example of the JSON output you want?

Comment: BlueMonkMN, yes, thank you, the data sample above works well.  Let me work through the ideas below and I'll be back.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to iterate through all the data, and build the table, as you suggest.  I would suggest using a `Dictionary`, with the timestamp as the key.  For each timestamp there can be multiple MotorData's, so it could have a list, like this:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, List<MotorDataModel>>
```

A code snippet to build this table would look like this:

```
List<MotorModel> motorModels;   // filled in previously
// build result structure in this dictionary:
Dictionary<DateTime, List<MotorDataModel>> table = new Dictionary<DateTime, List<MotorDataModel>>();
// iterate through all motors and their data, and fill in the table
foreach(MotorModel m in motorModels)
{
    foreach(MotorDataModel md in m.MotorData)
    {
        DateTime ts = md.timestamp;
        // if this is the first occurance of the timestamp, create new 'row'
        if (!table.ContainsKey(ts)) table[ts] = new List<MotorDataModel>();
        // add the data to the 'row' of this timestamp
        table[ts].Add(md);
    }
}

// output the table
foreach(DateTime ts in table.Keys)
{
    ...
    foreach(MotorDataModel md in table[ts])
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Json.NET from NewtonSoft.

```
JObject o = new JObject();

foreach (MotorModel mm in allData) {
    foreach (MotorDataModel mdm : mm.MotorData()) {
        string key = mdm.TimeStamp.ToString(); // Or do your own format
        o[key][mm.MotorName + ":kW"] = mdm.MotorKw;
        o[key][mm.MotorName + ":Speed"] = mdm.MotorSpeed;
        o[key][mm.MotorName + ":TEmp"] = mdm.MotorTemp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like this to compute your data:

```
var motorData = allData.SelectMany(x => x.MotorData).ToArray();
var starting = motorData.Min(x => x.timestamp);
var ending = motorData.Max(x => x.timestamp);
var duration = ending.Subtract(starting);
var blocks = (int)Math.Ceiling(duration.TotalMinutes / 15.0);

var query =
    from b in Enumerable.Range(0, blocks)
    let s = starting.AddMinutes(b * 15.0)
    let e = starting.AddMinutes((b + 1.0) * 15.0)
    select new
    {
        Timestamp = s,
        MotorSpeedAverage =
            motorData
                .Where(x => x.timestamp >= s && x.timestamp < e)
                .Average(x => x.MotorSpeed),
    };
```

I get this result:

[image: query]